# How to add `--sslAllowInvalidCertificates` on mongodb uri?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.4

I have a mongodb server requires `x.509 certificate`. So I have to use `--sslPEMKeyFile` and `--sslCAFile` on mongo shell command to connect to that server. It works fine. In my dev environment, I am using `--sslAllowInvalidCertificates` parameter. It works fine. But I wonder how I can use `--sslAllowInvalidCertificates` through `nodejs` driver. I have checked this link `http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/reference/connecting/connection-settings/` but it doesn't have the option for invalid certificates.

Answer (score 0):

There's a detailed post that might answer this question here:

[Connecting to MongoDB over SSL with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24381561/connecting-to-mongodb-over-ssl-with-node-js/)